# Understanding awk command usage while passing a file content in it

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
cat LIST.txt | awk 'BEGIN { print "POSTNT" ;} { print "NT Id= \""$1"\" id=\""$2"\" "}' | abc
```

Just to let everyone know:

Here `$1` is actually the first column from `cat LIST.txt` and `$2` is the second column from  that file. The columns should be tab separated.  This is not a question but a information.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946

Comment: @Kusalananda hi, I have already declared a fun. It is still failing.

Comment: You can't execute a string as a generic command like that, especially not when it's a pipeline. You also have a typo in that `=` must not have spaces around it.

Comment: ignore that space after =, that's a mistake while putting my question here. Any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: Problem is resolved. $2 is the second column from that file. So, $2 should always come from that file. Initially I thought I can replace it with any other variable like $ID but my understanding was wrong. I have enriched my .txt file with a second column that I needed there.

Comment: As an aside, more efficient to run `awk ... <LIST.txt` instead of `cat LIST.txt | awk ...`; it's a relatively small difference for awk, but can be a huge one with `wc -c` (which can operate in constant time with a real file handle but has to be O(n) with a pipe) or `sort` (which can parallelize with a real handle but has to read front-to-back with a pipe).

Comment: ...that said, if you no longer have a problem, it's appropriate to delete your question. If you *do* want to provide your own answer, you should do that by posting it separately, as an answer (so it can be voted on / considered the same as any other answer); as such, you should thus leave the question as a question, rather than editing it into something that isn't one.

Comment: Thanks Charles will try this next time :)

Comment: I have updated the title of the question to : Understanding awk command usage... Let me if that's ok

Answer (score 1):

Your command,

```
cat LIST.txt | awk 'BEGIN { print "POSTNT" ;} { print "NT Id= \""$1"\" id=\""$2"\" "}' | abc
```

may be slightly improved into

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "POSTNT" } { printf("NT Id=\"%s\" id=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2) }' <List.txt | abc
```

This just gets rid of the `cat` and also uses `printf` rather than `print`.  With `awk`, use `print` to print separate fields, as in

```
print "some data", $1, $2, "some other data", $4
```

This would print a record with five fields.  The fields would be delimited by the value of `OFS` (a space by default) and the record would be terminated by the value of `ORS` (newline by default).

Here, though, you format your own string for output, which is what `printf` is used for.

Comment: What is the question you're answering here? I didn't see "how can this code be improved?", and that would be off-topic for SO if it *were* explicitly asked.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wrote the answer since I thought that the given code could be made better using idiomatic constructs. I further explained the difference between `print` and `printf`. If you think that this was the wrong thing to do and would not benefit the questioner or anybody else, I will naturally delete the  answer.